# Update datatable in a modal (ajax javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, modal-dialog

[image: Listado]

I have a modal that contains a datatable that is called from another main datatable, to raise the modal I execute the following function with their respective validations

```
   var getDataDiseases = function (tbody, table)
    {
        $(tbody).on("click", "button.disease-button", function ()
        {
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
           
            var id = data.id;
            var fullName = data.fullName;

            if (id != null)
            {
                GetDiseases(id, fullName);
            }
            else
            {
                toastr.error('Ha ocurrido un problema, intente más tarde', "Error");
            }
        });
    }    

    getDataDiseases("#TableUsers tbody", table); 


 function GetDiseases(id, fullName)
    {  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/DiseaseTypes/GetDiseasesByUser",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (response)
            {
                ReloadDataTableModal(response);       

                var nombreUser = document.getElementById('title-strong-diseases');
                nombreUser.innerHTML = fullName

                $("#diseases-modal").modal();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
                console.log("error");
                toastr.error(error, "Error");
            }
        });     
     
    }
```

In the getDiseases function if the ajax call returns success, load or reload the datatable with the information answered through another function called ReloadDataTableModal which receives the information as a parameter

```
   function ReloadDataTableModal(response)
    {
        //Se destrute el Dt
        $('#TableDiseasesUser').DataTable().clear();
        $('#TableDiseasesUser').DataTable().destroy();

        var tableModal = $('#TableDiseasesUser').DataTable({          
            "processing": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "destroy": true,
            data: response,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "diseaseId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "diseaseName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "diseasedStatus", render: getToggleSwitch },

            ],
            fixedColumns: {
                heightMatch: 'none'
            },
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
            },
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                [25, 50, 100, 200, "Todos"]
            ]
        });

        var getDataDiseasesByUser = function (tbody, tableModal)
        {
            $(tbody).on("click", "input.toggle-disease", function ()
            { 
                var data = tableModal.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

                console.log($(this));
                console.log(data);

                ActionAddDiseaseToUser(data);
            });
        }

        getDataDiseasesByUser("#TableDiseasesUser tbody", tableModal);

    }
```

Within this same function, I also load the "click" listening event for when the swicht is turned on or off and thus update the datatable

The problem that is occurring is that the switch only works the first time it is executed, when it is executed for the second time the data is not found in the line marked by the arrow and therefore that variable has the value of undefined

[image: code]

To do this I print the value of each of the "TR" of the row that calls the modal button

[image: values]

What the ActionAddDiseaseToUser method does is update a column in the Database and return the new Json (by backend) to populate (update) again the datatable of the modal

```
  function ActionAddDiseaseToUser(data)
    {
        var userDiseaseObject = {};

        userDiseaseObject.userId = data.userId;
        userDiseaseObject.firstName = data.firstName;
        userDiseaseObject.lastName = data.lastName;
        userDiseaseObject.diseaseId = data.diseaseId;
        userDiseaseObject.diseaseName = data.diseaseName;
        userDiseaseObject.diseasedStatus = data.diseasedStatus;        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Users/AddDiseaseToUser",
            data: JSON.stringify(userDiseaseObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response)
                {                   
                    ReloadDataTableModal(response);

                    toastr.success('Se ha actualizado la enfermedad ' + data.diseaseName + ' al usuario ' + data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName, "Guardado");                
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
            {
                toastr.error(error, "Error");
            }
        });
    }
```

What's going on? Why does my logic only work the first time the switch is activated or deactivated? Why is it that the second time I click on the switch, I can't find the data in the corresponding row? I have destroyed and cleaned the datatable but it does not solve the problem ... any help for me?

**Current behavior:**

[image: error data]

Comment: Instead of using jQuery Ajax, use the Ajax function that comes with DataTables, it's much easier. https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: What exactly does it suggest? populate the dt another way using ajax? or occupy some additional parameter? could you complement your answer? @mark_b

Answer (score 1):

In your modal, have a table defined with an ID, a `<thead>` and an empty `<tbody>`.

```html
<table id="TableDiseasesUser" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Disease ID</th>
            <th>Disease Name</th>
            <th>Disease Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In your JavaScript, define your DataTable and assign it to a variable. Because you are using POST, the `ajax` property needs to be an object:

```js
const tableModal = $('#TableDiseasesUser').DataTable({          
    "processing": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "ajax": {
        method: "POST",
        url: "/DiseaseTypes/GetDiseasesByUser",
        data: { id: '' }
    }
    "columns": [
        { "data": "diseaseId", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "diseaseName", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "diseasedStatus", render: getToggleSwitch },
    ],
    fixedColumns: {
        heightMatch: 'none'
    },
    "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
        [25, 50, 100, 200, "Todos"]
    ]
});
```

In your server side code, return your data as JSON. You haven't shown me any so I don't know which language you use, but I use PHP

```php
$data = getMyData(); // returns an array
echo json_encode(["data" => $data]); // echo an object with property "data" that has value the $data array
```

Then when you want to (re-)populate your table you set the `ajax.data` property and call its `reload()` function

```js
function ReloadDataTableModal(newID) {
    tableModal.ajax.data = { id: newID };
    tableModal.ajax.reload();
}
```

For your click event, refer to the table variable you defined earlier

```js
tableModal.on('click', 'input.toggle-disease', function() {
    const data = tableModal.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
}
```

And that's it. No need to call `destroy()` or any of that.

Comment: Your solution works correctly when working on the same modal, but when going to the general list and raising another different modal, I keep getting the error, I have updated my question in the current behavior section I attach a gif of the result of your code

Comment: @CristofherAmbiado what is `dataModal`? I can't see it referenced anywhere in your code.

Comment: `tableModal.on('click', 'input.toggle-disease', function ()
        {
            var dataModal = tableModal.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

            ActionAddDiseaseToUser(dataModal, tableModal);
        });`

I have changed the name of the variable thinking that there was a problem in it, but as you can see it is basically the same code, what is happening? this keeps me awake! @mark_b